# Is there a perfect function in the standard library or some recommended methodology to expand escape sequences in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am taking user input in an application I am writing and would like to expand escape sequences that the user enters.

For example if the user enters `\\n` it will be interpreted into a str `\\\\n`. I want to, in a general way, interpret that string (into a newline) and similar ones.

I could of course use `String::replace()` on the most essential ones and live without the rest, but I would prefer a general solution that also handles hex escapes (`\x61` is `a`).

Answer (score 5):

Escapes are usually handled by the lexer / parser (basically they're part of the language grammar), I don't think there's an stdlib function which would manage them as it would be done as a much lower level.

Furthermore, escapes tend to be highly language-specific, in possibly unexpected ways. Rust has a [singularly small list of escape sequences](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#ascii-escapes), which is [probably desirable compared to the garbage available from C's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences), but I still do not know that you'd want to allow e.g. arbitrary hex or unicode escape sequences.

I would therefore recommend setting up your own explicitly supported list of escapes, though if you really do not want to [there are probably third-party packages which can help you](https://docs.rs/snailquote/0.3.0/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/snailquote/fn.unescape.html).

Comment: Fun fact: The Rust compiler source code does not contain the information that `\n` translates to the byte 10. The lexer [simply translates the escape sequence to the character `'\n'`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nightly-rustc/src/rustc_lexer/unescape.rs.html#178-185). The Rust binary that is used to compile the compiler knows the translation, which in turn was compiled by another Rust compiler and so on, until you get to some historic Rust compiler that was written in OCaml.